# Parameters for scanning integers into an array

Tags: arrays, integer, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a class that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 0 to 50 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered, ending the input by entering an integer outside of the range.

I'm not quite sure on how to limit the input to only 0 to 50 inclusively, and am asking for some help. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberCounter{

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

System.out.println("Enter integers between 0 to 50 (enter integers not "
+ "0 to 50 to terminate:");

while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    list.add(scan.nextInt());
}

Integer [] nums = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
   System.out.println(nums[i]);
  }
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would limit the range.

Change this:

```
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    list.add(scan.nextInt());
}
```

To this:

```
int number = scan.nextInt();
while(number >=0 && number <=50){
    list.add(number);
    number = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Although, I do not know the exact output you want from the code. Hope it helps.